# Getting Issues via REST API but not all

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I currently trying to get the issues from JIRA via REST API via this:

```
curl -D- -u USERNAME -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search? jql=project%20%3D%20MNG%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.4.0 \ 
-o release.json
```

But unfortunately i don't get all issues. Only 50 instead of 59. I already checked if all the issues have the correct `fixVersion` set to `3.4.0`.

But via browser:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20MNG%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.4.0

I got all the issues.

Do i oversight something ? Some idea hint ?

Comment: Maybe default pagination applied?

Comment: Hm. ? Is that active on rest api ?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 is a default value for "maxResults" parameter. Here's API documentation https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search